# AWS DMS Task getting failed after completion with error as AlwaysOn BACKUP-ed data is not available

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-dms

I have created DMS task for migrating data from one RDS MS SQL Server instance to another RDS MS SQL Server instance with "Full load + ongoing replication", and data copied to target instance but status showing as failed with below error -

> Last Error AlwaysOn BACKUP-ed data is not available Task error notification received from subtask 0, thread 0 [reptask/replicationtask.c:2822] [1020465] Error executing source loop; Stream component failed at subtask 0, component st_0_NJZW5VSVPASASA4E4N2SJGTVEZ3UIDLJHX3NDY; Stream component 'st_0_NJZW5VSVASASAZ4E4N2SJGTVEZ3UIDLJHX3NDY' terminated [reptask/replicationtask.c:2829] [1020465] Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL

Anything am I missing here?

Comment: Did you got any solution for this error as I am also getting the same error but data replication is also missing